# Horizontal divider with text in the middle in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, material-design

Is there a built in widget in Flutter to create a divider with text in the middle? Any guide on how to do it? Like this: (the "OR" text in the middle of horizontal line)

[here's is the screenshot of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyJXx.png)

Comment: `const Divider(),`

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can try to use the [Row](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) widget.

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Divider()
        ),       

        Text("OR"),        

        Expanded(
            child: Divider()
        ),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 61):

[image: Example Implementation of a divider with Text]

To expand on Jerome's answer - Here is an example that shows how to embed it with other content and also has additional edgeinsets for coming closer to the actual picture that you want:

```
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[Text("above")],
            ),
            Row(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 36,
                    )),
              ),
              Text("OR"),
              Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      height: 36,
                    )),
              ),
            ]),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[Text("below ")],
            ),
          ])
```

Comment: This actually a good example!

Answer (score 13):

There is no flutter widget that do this, I created on for myself.
You can do it like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class HorizontalOrLine extends StatelessWidget {
  const HorizontalOrLine({
    this.label,
    this.height,
  });

  final String label;
  final double height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 15.0),
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: height,
            )),
      ),

      Text(label),

      Expanded(
        child: new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 10.0),
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: height,
            )),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

The usage will be:

```
HorizontalOrLine(height: 10,label: "OR")
```

Answer (score 10):

I've beatified this a little and the code goes like this

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children: const [
                     Expanded(
                       child: Divider(
                                indent: 20.0,
                                endIndent: 10.0,
                                thickness: 1,
                              ),
                     ),
                     Text(
                          "OR",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                     ),
                     Expanded(
                          child: Divider(
                                  indent: 10.0,
                                  endIndent: 20.0,
                                  thickness: 1,
                          ),
                      ),
                ],
),
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to make a CustomPainter and draw a line

Follow the steps: [image]

CustomPainter:

```
class Drawhorizontalline extends CustomPainter {
      Paint _paint;
      bool reverse;

   Drawhorizontalline(this.reverse) {
     _paint = Paint()
          ..color = PPColors.tertiaryColor
          ..strokeWidth = 1
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
   }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
      if (reverse) {
         canvas.drawLine(Offset(-250.0, 0.0), Offset(-10.0, 0.0), _paint);
      } else {
         canvas.drawLine(Offset(10.0, 0.0), Offset(250.0, 0.0), _paint);
      }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

Use this CustomPainter

```
Widget getSeparateDivider() {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    CustomPaint(painter: Drawhorizontalline(true)),
    Text(
      "OR",
      style: TextStyle(
          color: PPColors.primaryColor,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: PPUIHelper.FontSizeLarge),
    ),
    CustomPaint(painter: Drawhorizontalline(false))
  ],
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a container to achieve this:

```
new Container(height: 40, width: 1, color: Colors.grey,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),),
```

If you want a vertical line, change the height for the size of it and control the "thickness" of your line with width.

Invert these logic between width / height if you want to draw an horizontal line.

Use it in a Row with your text in the middle of both of your containers.

Comment: Please try to explain your answer, as right now it is hard for me to understand what you are trying to say/do.

Comment: Since there is a Divider() widget for it, we don't need to create a Container which looks like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HorizontalLineTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final double lineHeight;
  final double lineWidth;
  final double paddingTop;
  final double paddingBottom;

  HorizontalLineTitle({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.color,
    this.lineHeight,
    this.lineWidth,
    this.paddingTop,
    this.paddingBottom,
  });

  Widget _line() {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxWidth = constraints.constrainWidth();
        final dashWidth = lineWidth ?? 10.0;
        final dashHeight = lineHeight ?? 1.0;
        final dashCount = (boxWidth / (2 * dashWidth)).floor();
        return Flex(
          children: List.generate(dashCount, (_) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: dashWidth,
              height: dashHeight,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
              ),
            );
          }),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgets = <Widget>[];
    widgets.add(Expanded(child: _line()));
    if (title != null && title != '') {
      widgets.add(Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      widgets.add(Container(width: 2.0));
    }
    widgets.add(Expanded(child: _line()));
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          0.0, paddingTop ?? 0.0, 0.0, paddingBottom ?? 0.0),
      child: Row(
        children: widgets,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget can be used for having the same thing you need but with dotted lines. Just wanted to post this so people can use it to customize it to their needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Divider()
        ),       

        Text("OR"),        

        Expanded(
            child: Divider()
        ),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer seems to be the same as [the accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058761/12349734) answer. Please dont post identical answers. Instead, upvote it (once you have enough reputation). for now, I'd recommend deleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Another solution, is to use **Stack** widget where we can stack two widgets - **Divider** and **Container**.

Using the **aligment** property on the **Stack** widget, we center all child widgets.

The Container has two properties that we need.

1. The **padding** property: to create margins around text.
2. The **decoration** property:  fills the entire space in the same color as the background.

```js
Stack(
 alignment: Alignment.center,
 children: [
   const Divider(),
   Container(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
     ),
     child: const Text(
       'OR',
       style: TextStyle(
         ...
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```