# How to draw a horizontal line in flutter row widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I have initialized a Row. Inside that, I created some Texts in a column and after that, I want to add a line but it is not showing anything. I have used Expanded for that reason and followed the given solutions-

[Horizontal divider with text in the middle in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058228/horizontal-divider-with-text-in-the-middle-in-flutter)

But none of them worked either.

Here's the image of my code output-

[image]

Here's my code-

```
Container(
      color:Colors.white,
      child: (
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Image(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  image: NetworkImage("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"),
                ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Book Name"),
                Text("Author name"),

                Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    ),
```

So, I need a line below the two texts and show it like the below picture-

[image]

Comment: try changing the color of the divider to black and remove the expanded

Comment: I have edited the code and still not working. Please check @Abbas.M

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Try wrapping you `Column` in an `Expanded` so the `Divider` knows how much space to occupy.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: (Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      // ...
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Book Name"),
            Text("Author name"),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  )),
);
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I have another query that my first text is taking some space at top and not having any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hmm, do you mean that it's indented to the right a bit?

Comment: No, it is taking some space at top.


  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

I have the above codes, but not working

Comment: I see, did you put those rules for the `Column` or the `Row`? You'll need the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` rule on the `Row` to get them at the top

Answer (score 8):

Easy Pezy Lemon Squeezy

Its simple, see take a container, do not mention its width, because it will take the space dynamically and then only give the color to the lower border of the radius.

```html
Container(
                              child: Text(
                                'Your Text Here',
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                  bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that you placed your `divider` inside a column whereas the divider by default is horizontal so it doesn't have enough space to occupy. If you change your `height` property for the `divider` you can see it clearly.

If you want you can wrap your `divider` in a `row` or perhaps make the `divider` part of the outer `row` though you might have to fix its alignment and wrap it in an `expanded`. You can also wrap the column in an expanded so it occupies all enough space for the divider to appear.

I'd do the code for you but I only have part of the code of what's displayed + it shouldn't be too difficult. If you needed more help let me know!

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly how long you want the line to be. You can wrap the `Divider` with a `SizedBox` specifying the width of the line with the `SizedBox` properties.

Answer (score 2):

use :
`Divider(),`

source : [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html)