# Assigning a Row to a Widget?

Tags: flutter

Started to learn Flutter, and I just finished the tutorial for my first app. I wanted to expand it by adding a picture and some text, so I pulled some code from this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964776/how-to-draw-a-horizontal-line-in-flutter-row-widgets) to see if I could get it to work:

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: (
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20.0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                  height:20,
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.asset(imagePath)
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Hello World"),
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is added to the Home page using:

```
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          DisplayPictureScreen(imagePath:'legoman.png'),
          BigCard(pair: pair),
          SizedBox(height: 10),

          ...
```

However I got this error, which I understand is a casting error:

```
lib/main.dart:221:14: Error: The argument type '(Row)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.
 - 'Row' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
      child: (
             ^
```

I guess did something change since 4 years ago from when that other thread came out? It seemed like that user had it working with no issue. If this isn't the way to do it now, what is the proper method to add a picture and a text with a divider?

Comment: Just remove the parenthesis and append `child: Row (...)` directly

Comment: Could you explain why removing the `(` would fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To make the code you mentioned work, You need to remove the parenthesis that contains the Row widget.

Make the code look like this:

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20.0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                  height:20,
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.asset(imagePath)
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Hello World"),
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```